# large unwanted margins in R saved bitmaps

Tags: r

Here is some R code to create a picture of random dots using plot() and then saving it with png(). I have also used bmp() tiff() and jpeg() and they all exhibit the same bad behaviour (see below). I am using windows 7

```
par(mar=rep(0,4),pty="s",oma=rep(0,4))
width<-512
height<-512
ndots<-500
x<-runif(ndots,min=0,max=width)
y<-runif(ndots,min=0,max=height)
png("dots.png",width=width,height=height)
plot(x,y,ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE,type='p',pch=15, cex=2,asp=1)
dev.off()
```

The bad behaviour: the saved file has a very big margin all around it, even though, as you see, I specified no outer or inner margins. And the plot window version of the plot inside R looks fine.

Please suggest how I can save the plot as a bitmap with no margin. I tried bitmap() but I don't have ghostscript installed and so it didn't work.

Thanks very much for any help

Comment: If one of the answers is a solution to your problem, would you mind marking it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to put the `par` command after the `png` command.

```
png("dots.png",width=width,height=height)
par(mar=rep(0,4),pty="s",oma=rep(0,4))
plot(x,y,ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE,type='p',pch=15, cex=2,asp=1)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
width<-512
height<-512
ndots<-500
x<-runif(ndots,min=0,max=width)
y<-runif(ndots,min=0,max=height)
png("dots.png",width=width,height=height)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0) + 0.1,pty="s",oma=rep(0,4))
plot(x,y,ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE,type='p',pch=15, cex=2,asp=1)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks! Works a charm

Comment: @BillSimpson Please accept the answer if solution has worked for you.